# Does AWS charge for Fargate image pull from ECR in the same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have:

- Fargate container
- Private ECR repository

They're in the same account and region. Will AWS charge me for pulling images?

ECR pricing page says `Data transferred between Amazon Elastic Container Registry and Amazon EC2 within a single region is free of charge (i.e., $0.00 per GB).` Does it mean only EC2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS container team member here. I have followed up with the ECR PM and they confirmed this is applicable to Fargate (and Lambda) in addition to EC2. I have asked the team to work on the documentation and update it to reflect this. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: Please can we have an update on [this thread](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/696)

Comment: Be assured that the fact we don't post often on that thread does not mean we are not monitoring it very closely and we are not working on it. Unfortunately there is no update we can share at the moment other than reassuring we want to address that use case as soon as possible.